# Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'LocaleOptions'

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

Hello I am trying make this sample code which is in from **moment** into luxon that is given below,

```
const date8 = '';

console.log(`This moment date Method 8 :  `, moment(date8[0]).startOf('hour'));
```

**Received Output:**

```
   This moment date Method 8 : 2022-12-02T14:00:00.000Z
```

When I had convert this into luxon and using this format I had got my expected output which I am looking for,

```
const date9 = '';

console.log(
  `This luxon date Method 8 :  `,
  luxon.DateTime.utc(date9[0]).startOf('hour')
);
```

**Received Output:**

```
  This luxon date Method 8 : 2022-12-02T14:00:00.000Z
```

But in the **VSCode** I am receiving this error.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 8, '(year: number, options?: LocaleOptions | undefined): DateTime', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 8, '(options?: LocaleOptions | undefined): DateTime', gave the following error.
    Type 'Date' has no properties in common with type 'LocaleOptions'.
```

Here I do not understand I had received same output as like moment in the luxon but why I am still facing this error when i hover in

```
(date[0])
```

This is the copy of code source link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-61jt3q?file=index.js

Comment: So it works, but VSCode's linter incorrectly flags it? What's the problem? Just ignore the false positive.

Comment: How can I ignore the false positive? @samuei

Comment: By...ignoring it. It's not stopping execution, so it's just VSCode complaining. Ignore VSCode's complaint.